# accepts_nested_attributes_for and validates_uniqueness_of generate bad sql requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-activerecord

I have strange validations requests. Here's my code :

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exchanges_users, inverse_of: :user
end

#app/models/exchange.rb
class Exchange < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exchanges_users, inverse_of: :exchange
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :exchanges_users, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => :all_blank
end

#app/models/exchanges_user.rb
class ExchangesUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :exchange
  validates_presence_of :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :exchange, :scope => [:user]

  belongs_to :exchange, inverse_of: :exchanges_users
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :exchanges_users
end
```

And, in the console, when I try to create an Exchange :

```
e = Exchange.new({"name"=>"Test", "exchanges_users_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"user_id"=>"4"}, "1"=>{"user_id"=>"1"}}}) ; e.save
```

Rails validates the uniqueness with these requests :

```
SELECT  1 AS one FROM "exchanges_users" WHERE ("exchanges_users"."exchange_id" IS NULL AND "exchanges_users"."user_id" = 4) LIMIT 1
SELECT  1 AS one FROM "exchanges_users" WHERE ("exchanges_users"."exchange_id" IS NULL AND "exchanges_users"."user_id" = 1) LIMIT 1
```

Obviously, the "IS NULL" part is wrong, but I don't know why this happen. Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Obviously, the `IS NULL` part is right. You're validating `ExchangeUser`'s `Exchange` that is not yet saved to the database, so it doesn't have an `id` at all. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I simplified the problem for SO. My exchanges_user model have some attributes. I need these 3 models. Yes the validation happen before the save of the exchange. Maybe I can change that ?

Comment: What is the expected behavior?  Is there something other than the `id` that makes an `Exchange` unique?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `validates_presence_of :exchange` this query should be benign, but useless. You can solve this by creating the `Exchange` record first and and applying its attributes

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  e = Exchange.new
  e.save!(validate: false) 
  e.update_attributes({"name"=>"Test", "exchanges_users_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"user_id"=>"4"}, "1"=>{"user_id"=>"1"}}}) 
  e.save!
end
```